# excel vba code to turn on and off comments

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for vba code to turn on and off Excel comments - I am using them for online help.

```
Sub CommentsToggle_Click()
    If Help.Caption = "HELP" Then
    'If IsEmpty(Comments) = True Then
       Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator
       Help.Caption = "HIDE COMMENTS"
    Else
       Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
      ' Comments = 1
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: If an answers helps solve your problem please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark next to that answer. I noticed you have not done this on the questions you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using a toggle button, in which case you have to check the status of the toggle button before doing anything

```
Sub CommentsToggle_Click()
    If CommentsToggle.Value = True Then 'The toggle button is pressed
       Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentAndIndicator
       Help.Caption = "HIDE COMMENTS"
    Else 'The toggle button is depressed :(
       Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
       Help.Caption = "HELP"
    End If
 End Sub
```